Angular 17 Di class interceptor does not handle asynchronous operation
I added firebase auth in my angular app. For authorization purpose I created interceptor and called firebase getToken stream(asynchronous).I tried every solutions from youtube  tutorial ,they store the token in localStorage then used it inside the interceptor i think it maybe cause a security issues.The problem i faced is infinite loading app in browser or it prevent all http api calls from backend(exclude firebase auth calls).
AuthService:
import { Injectable, inject, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { Auth, 
         createUserWithEmailAndPassword, 
         sendEmailVerification, 
         sendPasswordResetEmail, 
         signInWithEmailAndPassword, 
         signInWithPopup, 
         signOut, 
         updateProfile,

type here

         user,
        
         idToken
        
        } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { Observable, from, switchMap } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../models/user.model';
import { GoogleAuthProvider } from '@angular/fire/auth';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  firebaseAuth=inject(Auth);
  user$ = user(this.firebaseAuth);
  currentUserSig = signal<User | null | undefined>(undefined);
  authToken$ = idToken(this.firebaseAuth);
  register(email:string,username:string,password:string):Observable<void>{
    const promise = createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.firebaseAuth,email,password).then(
      response => 
        {
          sendEmailVerification(response.user)
          updateProfile(response.user,{displayName:username})
        }
    );
    return from(promise);
  }

  logIn(email:string,password:string):Observable<void>{
     const promise = signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      this.firebaseAuth,
      email,
      password,
      
      ).then(()=>{});
      return from (promise);
  }


  logOut():Observable<void>{
    const promise = signOut(this.firebaseAuth).then(response=> console.log(response));
    
    return from (promise);
  }

  forgetPassword(email:string):Observable<void>{
     const promise = sendPasswordResetEmail(this.firebaseAuth,email);
     return from (promise);
  }

  googleSignIn():Observable<void>{
        const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
        provider.addScope('profile');
        provider.addScope('email');
        provider.setCustomParameters({
          prompt: 'select_account'
        });
   const promise = signInWithPopup(this.firebaseAuth,provider).then(
    response =>{
      console.log(response);
    }
   )

   return from (promise);
  }

 

  
}


AuthInterceptor
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, switchMap, take } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    return this.authService.authToken$.pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap(token => {
        const authReq = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : ''
          }
        });
        return next.handle(authReq);
      })
    );
  }

}

Any solutions for fix this problem?

I think your intercept must be as
intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
return this.authService.authToken$.subscribe(
  token => {
    const authReq = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });
    return next.handle(authReq);
  })}

